# ExifReader.ReadJpeg issue

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a problem in my camera app

I am using PhotoCaptureDevice for capture photo.captured response got in a stream format

when I try to read ExifReader.ReadJpeg return always same value( zero) in wp8.How to fix this issue?

my code for check image is in the landscape mode or not

```
private bool IsLandscape(Stream imgstrm)
{
    JpegInfo info = ExifReader.ReadJpeg(imgstrm, "");

    if (info.Orientation == ExifOrientation.BottomRight || info.Orientation == ExifOrientation.TopLeft)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Using my psychic powers: are you reading something from the stream before calling `IsLandscape`?

Comment: No i got some result-[link](http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2012/11/windows-phone-8-photo-orientation-exif-bug.html) 
is it true?

Comment: Well, whether it's true or not, it doesn't explain why `ExifReader.ReadJpeg` **always** returns 0. Or maybe all the test pictures you're using are oriented the same way?

Comment: No. i took picture panorama and pivot mode .but it return same value

Comment: Set the stream Position to 0 before calling ReadJpeg! For the orientation issues, simple - set the breakpoint at "if ... " and see what the ExifOrientation value is for different orientations. Also, you're not checking for Undefined value I think.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/23/working-with-pictures-in-camera-tasks-in-windows-phone-7-orientation-rotation.aspx), Exifreader has some issues with stream like your's. Please follow the model described in the post (method overloading) to get the JpegInfo object from it.